# Use single quote and double quote same time as string python

Tags: python, double-quotes, single-quotes

How can I use single quote and double quote same time as string python?
For example:

```
string = "Let's print "Happines" out"
```

result should be Let's print `"Happines"` out

I tried to use backslash but it prints out a `\` before 's that should be.

Comment: You're probably mixing up the `repr` representation of the string and the actual string contents. Try using backslashes and then printing the string with `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python there's lots of ways to write string literals.

For this example you can:

```
print('Let\'s print "Happiness" out')
print("Let's print \"Happiness\" out")
print('''Let's print "Happiness" out''')
print("""Let's print "Happiness" out""")
```

Any of the above will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this string:

```
string = "Let's print "Happines" out"
```

If you want to mix quotes, use the triple single quotes:

```
>>> string = '''Let's print "Happines" out'''
>>> print(string)
Let's print "Happines" out
```

Using triple quotes is acceptable too:

```
>>> string = """Let's print "Happines" out"""
>>> print(string)
Let's print "Happines" out
```